# Looping over a string missing the last char

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am new to C++ and am trying to read each char from a string one by one. Here is what I am doing:

```
string sum = "1 + 3 x 2\n";
char delimiter = ' ';
string token = "";
vector<string> tokens;

for(char c: sum)
{
    if(c == delimiter)
    {
        tokens.push_back(token);
        token = "";
    } 
    else 
    {
        token += c;
    }
}
```

So I am basically tokenizing my string. In my mind, I should end up with:

```
tokens[0] = "1";
tokens[1] = "+";
tokens[2] = "3";
tokens[3] = "x";
tokens[4] = "2";
```

However, when I run this I am not getting the final "2". I think this is because of the linebreak (this is necessary, not worth explaining".

Why is this happening?

Comment: Yes it is because there is no separator (space) after your 2. What you could do is check that `(c == delimiter) || (c == '\n')`

Comment: You got it. If you had put this as an answer I would have +1'ed you. Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change delimiter form being a char to being a string and then check if c is in that string.

```
string sum = "1 + 3 x 2\n";
string delimiters = " \n";
string token = "";
vector<string> tokens;

for(char c: sum)
{
    if(delimiters.find(c) != string::npos)
    {
        tokens.push_back(token);
        token = "";
    } 
    else 
    {
        token += c;
    }
}
```

This should also account for the newline at the end.

Comment: You could also use the cctype header and use isspace(c) to check if it is empty space, but that is slightly deprecated as is a port from old C functions and also this is more flexible as you can choose the delimiters you want.

Answer (score 0):

With your code, the token is pushed onto the vector after a space is found. Since there is no space after the 2, the 2 is not pushed.

What you could do to fix this is check for the newline at the end `if(c == delimiter || c == '\n')`